# Controllers in subfolders not working

Tags: php, json

my site was working fine on local .. but when i uploaded it online ... there is an issue ..

the controllers that are in a sub-dir are not working ... but the ones that are on main are working fine ...

domain.com/main is working 
domain.com/users/alerts/youralerts is not working ...

in the above example .. i have a folder in controllers called "users" in which i have a controller called "alerts" and in which i have a function called "youralerts" ... it did not return page not found but instead gave me a blank page ...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

all my functions in any controllers in any dir are giving this blank page .. 
I am just using one level deep dir ... so there is no folder within a folder.

about routes, i tried setting up ...

$route['users'] = 'users/alerts/youralerts'; and then access just /users ... didn't work 
$route['users'] = 'users'; didnt work

tried a few others too ... am I missing something?

on further investigation I found out that controllers in the dir are working but the controllers that are secured by secured class are not ... here is the code for my secured classes

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
public function is_post()
{
return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
}


<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Secure_Controller extends MY_Controller {


function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();

//
// Require members to be logged in. If not logged in, redirect to the login page.
//
if( ! $this->ion_auth->logged_in())
{
redirect(base_url() . 'main/login');
}
}

}
```

again its all working fine on local ...

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hard to say what the problem is without seeing any source code. I would suggest adding your routes to this so that you can get help quicker. Also as another thought are you using an htaccess file routing to your router or how are you going about that aspect? With a little more information im sure the problem can be solved in no time.

Comment: Thanks Cameebo ... on further investigation I found out that controllers in the dir are working but the controllers that are secured by secured class are not ... here is the code for my secured classes

see it in the question